# 8088/8086 WAIT instruction and the BIU

Tags: x86, x86-16

When the 8086/8088 executes a WAIT instruction, does the whole processor go idle, or just the EU? The Intel iAPX 86/88 User's Manual(1981,p2.18) doesn't specify whether or not the BIU stops prefetching as well.

Comment: A reasonable question, but it's going to require someone older than me to give an authoritative answer. :-) My guess would be that the BIU does indeed have to stop prefetching while waiting, but I don't have a source for that. But if you think about it, you're waiting for the TEST input pin to be asserted (which is connected to the BUSY pin on the x87 FPU), and the only way the processor can test that is over the bus. You only get parallel execution if you can arrange the code so that you aren't dependent on the results of a FP operation until you can be sure it's completed.

Comment: Hmm. I was leaning the other way. The test signal has a dedicated pin on the processor, so I understood it to be independent of the bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a late reply here but I believe I have confirmed that it does continue prefetching. As it happens, a friend of mine has built a custom 8088 computer for testing precisely things like this. It is able to execute a small program, logging the state of a subset of the cpu pins on each clock cycle, specifically it logs the address/data bus, the S0-S2 pins and the QS0-QS1 pins.

To test this specific case we just placed a JMP at the reset vector, and a WAIT instruction at the jump destination. That way the prefetch queue will be empty when the WAIT executes and any fetches seen on the bus after that would indicate that the BIU keeps prefetching during the WAIT.

The full log looks like this:

```
Cycle: 0000  Address(/data): 0xfb0bf  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (070fb0bf)
Cycle: 0001  Address(/data): 0xfb0bf  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (070fb0bf)
Cycle: 0002  Address(/data): 0xfb0bf  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (070fb0bf)
Cycle: 0003  Address(/data): 0xfb0bf  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (070fb0bf)
Cycle: 0004  Address(/data): 0xfb0bf  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (070fb0bf)
Cycle: 0005  Address(/data): 0xff0bf  S:  PASS  QS: 10 (170ff0bf)
Cycle: 0006  Address(/data): 0xfb0bf  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (070fb0bf)
Cycle: 0007  Address(/data): 0xffff0  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (040ffff0)
Cycle: 0008  Address(/data): 0x2ffea  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (0402ffea)
Cycle: 0009  Address(/data): 0x2ffea  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702ffea)
Cycle: 0010  Address(/data): 0x2ffea  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702ffea)
Cycle: 0011  Address(/data): 0xffff1  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (040ffff1)
Cycle: 0012  Address(/data): 0x2ff5b  S: FETCH  QS: 01 (0c02ff5b)
Cycle: 0013  Address(/data): 0x2ff5b  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702ff5b)
Cycle: 0014  Address(/data): 0x2ff5b  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702ff5b)
Cycle: 0015  Address(/data): 0xffff2  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (040ffff2)
Cycle: 0016  Address(/data): 0x2ffe0  S: FETCH  QS: 11 (1c02ffe0)
Cycle: 0017  Address(/data): 0x2ffe0  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702ffe0)
Cycle: 0018  Address(/data): 0x2ffe0  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702ffe0)
Cycle: 0019  Address(/data): 0xffff3  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (040ffff3)
Cycle: 0020  Address(/data): 0x2ff00  S: FETCH  QS: 11 (1c02ff00)
Cycle: 0021  Address(/data): 0x2ff00  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702ff00)
Cycle: 0022  Address(/data): 0x2ff00  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702ff00)
Cycle: 0023  Address(/data): 0xffff4  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (040ffff4)
Cycle: 0024  Address(/data): 0x2fff0  S: FETCH  QS: 11 (1c02fff0)
Cycle: 0025  Address(/data): 0x2fff0  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702fff0)
Cycle: 0026  Address(/data): 0x2fff0  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702fff0)
Cycle: 0027  Address(/data): 0xffff5  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (040ffff5)
Cycle: 0028  Address(/data): 0x2ff30  S: FETCH  QS: 11 (1c02ff30)
Cycle: 0029  Address(/data): 0x2ff30  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702ff30)
Cycle: 0030  Address(/data): 0x2ff30  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702ff30)
Cycle: 0031  Address(/data): 0x2ff30  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702ff30)
Cycle: 0032  Address(/data): 0x2ffb2  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702ffb2)
Cycle: 0033  Address(/data): 0x2ffba  S:  PASS  QS: 10 (1702ffba)
Cycle: 0034  Address(/data): 0x2ffff  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702ffff)
Cycle: 0035  Address(/data): 0xfe05b  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (040fe05b)
Cycle: 0036  Address(/data): 0x2e09b  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (0402e09b)
Cycle: 0037  Address(/data): 0x2e09b  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e09b)
Cycle: 0038  Address(/data): 0x2e09b  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e09b)
Cycle: 0039  Address(/data): 0xfe05c  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (040fe05c)
Cycle: 0040  Address(/data): 0x2e012  S: FETCH  QS: 01 (0c02e012)
Cycle: 0041  Address(/data): 0x2e012  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e012)
Cycle: 0042  Address(/data): 0x2e012  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e012)
Cycle: 0043  Address(/data): 0xfe05d  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (040fe05d)
Cycle: 0044  Address(/data): 0x2e034  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (0402e034)
Cycle: 0045  Address(/data): 0x2e034  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e034)
Cycle: 0046  Address(/data): 0x2e034  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e034)
Cycle: 0047  Address(/data): 0xfe05e  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (040fe05e)
Cycle: 0048  Address(/data): 0x2e056  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (0402e056)
Cycle: 0049  Address(/data): 0x2e056  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e056)
Cycle: 0050  Address(/data): 0x2e056  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e056)
Cycle: 0051  Address(/data): 0xfe05f  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (040fe05f)
Cycle: 0052  Address(/data): 0x2e078  S: FETCH  QS: 00 (0402e078)
Cycle: 0053  Address(/data): 0x2e078  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e078)
Cycle: 0054  Address(/data): 0x2e078  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e078)
Cycle: 0055  Address(/data): 0x2e078  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e078)
Cycle: 0056  Address(/data): 0x2e0f8  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e0f8)
Cycle: 0057  Address(/data): 0x2e0f8  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e0f8)
Cycle: 0058  Address(/data): 0x2e0f8  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e0f8)
Cycle: 0059  Address(/data): 0x2e0fa  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e0fa)
Cycle: 0060  Address(/data): 0x2e0fa  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e0fa)
...
Cycle: 0255  Address(/data): 0x2e0fa  S:  PASS  QS: 00 (0702e0fa)
```

At cycle 7 we can see the reset vector (0xffff0) being placed on the address bus, and on the next cycle we se 0xea (JMP) on the data bus. It's a long jump to f000:e05b so after that we see four additional fetches, returning 5b, e0, 00, and f0.

At cycle 27 we can see that even though this is an unconditional jump, the cpu prefetches one byte from the instruction after the jump, in this case 0x30 (XOR).

Starting at cycle 31 we have a completely passive bus cycle as the JMP is being processed and at cycle 33 we get queue status 10 meaning "Empty the Queue".
So at this point the prefetch queue is emptied (the XOR is discarded) and at cycle 35 we fetch from 0xfe05b and receive 0x9b, ie WAIT.

And, clearly, after this we can see four fetches on the bus, confirming that the prefetching continued during the WAIT. It should be noted that the fetch on cycle 39 happens before the wait has been executed. On cycle 40 we see queue status 01 ("First Byte of Opcode from Queue") so that's when the WAIT is fed into the EU, but we still see another three fetches after this.

Finally we can confirm that the cpu is indeed stuck waiting for the test pin, because after cycle 51, there is no more activity on the bus and QS never shows anything other than 00.

Comment: Wow. That's a fantastic answer. I need to digest your data for a while. I should also probably check in on this site more often. Thanks for doing this. Cheers!